# php mysql timeAgo function problems

Tags: php

Hello got problem can't figure out why my timeago function wont work keep display 49 years? when its created at March 14, 2018 1:06pm don't know what went wrong still won't display correct time ago it should be 1 second or 6 second once i press submit but it would display instead 49years.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RhJC.png)

Here is my ticket.php

```
public static function getTicket(){

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tickets` ";

   $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
   echo '<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-responsive"><th>User</th><th>Message</th><th>Created</th><th>Last update</th>';
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      // output data of each row
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<tr class="table_row">
                <td>' . $row['Message'] . '</td>
                <td>' . date("F j, Y, g:i a", strtotime($row['date'])) . '</td>
                 <td>' . timeAgo($row['editdate']) . '</td>
                 <td><form method="POST">
                  <input name="ticketId" value="' . $row['ticketid'] . '" type="text" hidden />
                  <button type="submit"   class="'.$class .'">'.$row['status'] .'</button></form>
                  </td>
                </tr>';
}
```

Here is my timeAgo function.php

```
<?php
function timeAgo($time_ago)
{

    $cur_time   = time();
    $time_elapsed   = $cur_time - $time_ago;
    $seconds    = $time_elapsed ;
    $minutes    = round($time_elapsed / 60 );
    $hours      = round($time_elapsed / 3600);
    $days       = round($time_elapsed / 86400 );
    $weeks      = round($time_elapsed / 604800);
    $months     = round($time_elapsed / 2600640 );
    $years      = round($time_elapsed / 31207680 );
    // Seconds
    if($seconds <= 60){
        return "just now";
    }
    //Minutes
    else if($minutes <=60){
        if($minutes==1){
            return "one minute ago";
        }
        else{
            return "$minutes minutes ago";
        }
    }
    //Hours
    else if($hours <=24){
        if($hours==1){
            return "an hour ago";
        }else{
            return "$hours hrs ago";
        }
    }
    //Days
    else if($days <= 7){
        if($days==1){
            return "yesterday";
        }else{
            return "$days days ago";
        }
    }
    //Weeks
    else if($weeks <= 4.3){
        if($weeks==1){
            return "a week ago";
        }else{
            return "$weeks weeks ago";
        }
    }
    //Months
    else if($months <=12){
        if($months==1){
            return "a month ago";
        }else{
            return "$months months ago";
        }
    }
    //Years
    else{
        if($years==1){
            return "one year ago";
        }else{
            return "$years years ago";
        }
    }
}



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please pass **$row['editdate']** value converting in seconds using **strtotime()** function.

```
timeAgo(strtotime($row['editdate']));
```

After this,you can get a difference from current time and given time in seconds.Without converting in seconds,php considering default timestamp value as **January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT** in your **$time_ago** variable and you got 49 year difference.

Hope you understand.

Comment: After i update still stuck displaying just now even after few minutes and my database for my editdate is timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP